# Cannot list Ad Accounts in facebook app

Tags: facebook, angularjs, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a pure-html/js web application (actually I'm using AngularJS; with "pure" I mean: I'm not using any server side technology) which uses a Facebook-Connect button like this:

```
<fb:login-button max_rows="1" size="xlarge" scope="email,public_profile,ads_management" show_faces="false" auto_logout_link="false"></fb:login-button>
```

Such button asks for permission: `ads_management` and basic user data. I'm testing ad-management functionality.

However, I ask two queries to facebook inside a controller:

```
$scope.fetchData = function() {
    FB.api('/me', function(response){
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            console.log("InApp::fetchData()");
            console.log(response);
            console.log("~InApp::fetchData()")
        });
    });
};
$scope.fetchAccounts = function() {
    FB.api('/me/adaccounts', function(response){
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            console.log("InApp::fetchAccounts()");
            console.log(response);
            console.log("~InApp::fetchAccounts()");
        });
    });
};
$scope.fetchAccountData = function(account_id) {

};

$scope.fetchData();
$scope.fetchAccounts();
```

For narrow-purposes I just printed the contents of a controller. Assume such controller exists, requires the person is logged in Facebook, and the user is currently logged in.

**My Issues are**:

1. The Login button does not update the page when I login. This is because no `onlogin=` was put. **Question**: How can I assign such attribute in an Angular way? (i.e. the handler coming from the scope).
2. `$scope.fetchData` is successfully executed. However, `$scope.fetchAccounts` is not. I'm asking this because I included the `ads_management` permission in the button. **Question**: What am I missing? (error: code: 10
   message: "(#10) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action"
   type: "OAuthException"). **Edit - Additional notes**: I deauthorized the application in my account, and reauthorized it: It never asks me the `ads_management` permission in the popup dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question, no idea. The second question, your app is not whitelisted for Ads API usage. Look into the Ads APi documentation on how to request access.